# Default ng-selected option does not appear in form POST without touching

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a select list in which one option is selected by default by ng-selected.
When  selecting default option value and submitting by post method it does not appear in post variables.Its working fine when I change to some other options and back.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="newItem.if_unmard_rsn">
   <option value="Under age" ng-selected="'Under Age'">Under Age
   </option>
   <option value="Health Issue">Health Issue
   </option>
   <option value="Economical Issue">Economical Issue
   </option>
   <option value="No reason">No Reason
   </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="newItem.if_unmard_rsn" ng-init="newItem.if_unmard_rsn='Under Age'">
  <option value="Under age" >Under Age
  </option>
  <option value="Health Issue">Health Issue
  </option>
  <option value="Economical Issue">Economical Issue
  </option>
  <option value="No reason">No Reason
  </option>
```

Comment: Now i am getting an empty option being selected Which is added by angular itself.

Comment: Yes.the default option is selected,but does not appear in post.

Comment: there many be something wrong with your post code. can you psot it

Comment: this is the code for button ``<button ng-if="action=='save'" type="button" class="btn btn-green"  ng-click="formSubmit(newItem)"><?php echo $this->lang->line('label_save'); ?></button>`` and post code is ``$scope.formSubmit = function(data) {
    FamilyMem.save(data, function (response) { 
    }, function (error) { 
    });
  };``